# How can I execute code after sending my response when I use cloudflare workers

Tags: api, discord, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I just followed [Discord's tutorial for hosting an application on a cloudflare worker](https://discord.com/developers/docs/tutorials/hosting-on-cloudflare-workers). I'm trying to convert one of my bots but I've been having a problem for a few days now, I can't figure out how to use deffer reply. When I return my reply with type 5 (DEFERRED_CHANNEL_MESSAGE_WITH_SOURCE) but after my request, my worker stops and the code that follows does not execute.

My question is how can I execute code after sending my response when I use cloudflare workers.

Here is my code:

```js
// [...]
router.post('/', async (request, env) => {
    const message = await request.json();
    console.log(message);
    if (message.type === InteractionType.APPLICATION_COMMAND) {
        switch (message.data.name.toLowerCase()) {
            case SETUP.name.toLowerCase(): {
                sendDeferedReply(message, env); // Take a few seconds to run
                return new JsonResponse({
                    type: 5,
                })
            }
});
});
// [...]
export default {
    async fetch(request, env) {
        if (request.method === 'POST') {
            const signature = request.headers.get('x-signature-ed25519');
            const timestamp = request.headers.get('x-signature-timestamp');
            console.log(signature, timestamp, env.DISCORD_PUBLIC_KEY);
            const body = await request.clone().arrayBuffer();
            const isValidRequest = verifyKey(
                body,
                signature,
                timestamp,
                env.DISCORD_PUBLIC_KEY
            );
            if (!isValidRequest) {
                console.error('Invalid Request');
                return new Response('Bad request signature.', { status: 401 });
            }
        }
        return router.handle(request, env);
    },
};
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `waitUntil()` to schedule work that happens after the response. The runtime will wait up to 30 seconds after the response has been sent for `waitUntil()` tasks to complete before tearing down the event context.

```js
async fetch(request, env, ctx) {
  // ...
  ctx.waitUntil(someAsyncFunction());
  return response;
}
```